# Why NOT to use NoSQL for relational information?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, relational-database, rethinkdb, nosql

So I'm a longtime developer / implementor of SQL DBs in my projects, but a few years back I ran into annoyances with Hierarchal data and I'd turned to XML and XQuery for a number of small projects, but never really found a DB that would handle concurrent XML read/write properly (using PHP).

I recently decided to read a little more on NoSQL DBs and try and understand the benefits they offer. People seem to continuously warn about avoiding storing relational data in them, or using them like a relational DB.

I've read a number of similar posts here, but not seen any clear indication as to where the line is. I guess I'm struggling to understand what the consequences are of 'misusing' a NoSQL model.

If we take the common 'Blog' example, I'm curious to understand where data 'should' be stored and why....

- Users
- Blog
- Posts
- Tags
- Comments/Replies

I feel I could implement this in SQL relatively simply, but the idea of Hierarchal Tags or Comments/Replies would be a pain, but again not impossible. It would seem to me that this type of data is better suited to NoSQL or Graph.

In a NoSQL structure, I feel that there are arguments to potentially Store all of this information in a single Document, stemming from say the 'User' but I'm unsure if this would be  considered correct?

If you had a senario whereby Many Users authored the document it might be less acceptable.

I've been looking at MongoDB, CouchDB and RethinkDB. Rethink seems interesting and seems to encourage 'Joining' and relationships, but that seems anti-NoSQL to the majority of the bits I've read.

I'm looking to probably code a simple Comment/Discussion system in PHP to help me get to know NoSQL and I feel that it suits this type of project, but I'm unsure what the best practice would be to structuring the Document(s). I obviously also then have concerns over how to mass-update if the information is repeated in multiple Documents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no general "NoSQL model" or "NoSQL structure". Every NoSQL database handles things differently and has its own preferred solutions for different problems.

Comment: You can get free online courses at university.mongodb.com, examples about schema for documents is a blog. During courses, they explain that schema for documents depends from the application. Users document will not be the same depending your goals.

Comment: NoSQL basically means just "not SQL", so many things can fit there.

RethinkDB tries to bring the best of both world by having flexible schemas, but still letting you efficiently join documents as needed.

In the case of a blog, you can use the same data model as with PostGres/mySQL

Comment: It seems like a Commenting/Discussion structure is natively Hierarchial and would therefore benefit from a XML / NoSQL system, but at the same time I see many elements which would 'relate' to a comment post and therefore complicate the choice... I guess its not black and white, but are people seriously reinventing/coding joins on top of NoSQL to get the relationship functionality? RethinkDB seemed a good fit, but performance looks pretty bad.

Comment: ... is the coding practice to literally pull out everything you need then iterate manually (post-process)? Seems a step back?